# How to add custom links based on a field to action bar?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting

Assume we have the action bar in SharePoint for document libraries. Assuming I want to create a simple link like `https://foobar.com/some-great-action?id=$ListItemID`, how I can do that the easiest way?

[image]

Preferred with a way where scripting works and no Visual Studio and C# is required.

> **Important**: I just need that for files; not for folders. Although the screenshot might imply something different.

Comment: Do you want this for folders or just documents?

Comment: Just documents, thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using ListView Command Set extension**:

If you want the new command in top bar you have to develop a SPFx **ListView Command Set extension**.

You can find more information at: [Build your first ListView Command Set extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api)

---

**Using Column formatting**:

If there is no requirement to have the link/button in top bar only, you can create a link using SharePoint JSON column formatting capabilities. This is an **easiest way** without SPFx development.

Use below JSON in **Format this column** option:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "Click here to open link",
  "attributes": {
    "href": {
      "operator": "+",
      "operands": [
        "https://foobar.com/some-great-action?id=",
        "[$ID]"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can use this JSON on any [supported column](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types) in document library, few suggestions:

1. Use default `Title` column if you are not using it for storing specific document titles.
2. Create a calculated column with formula `=[Title]` & use above JSON on this new column
3. Create a **Single line of text** column --> Add it to library view --> Hide it from library forms/properties form (optional).

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)